# How to remove sprite completely from screen pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I hit coins(collectibles) in my game they must disappear totally from the screen but that doesn't happen. After hitting it does disappear but it is still there which increases my score when I'm at the position of coins

Here's the code for checking collision :

```
# This function works for Coins Only
def coinsHit_or_not(self, hero, thecoin):
    hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(hero, thecoin)

    if hit:
        thecoin.hit()
        self.score += 2
```

and my Coin Class (it includes hit() function):

```py
class Coins(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    coinsFadeAway = [pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS1.png'), pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS2.png'),
                     pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS3.png'), pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS4.png'),
                     pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS5.png'), pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS6.png'),
                     pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS7.png'), pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS8.png'),
                     pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS9.png'), pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS10.png'),
                     pygame.image.load('CoinsFadeAway/CS11.png')]

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.coinTouched = False
        self.coins = pygame.image.load('CoinOG_Small.png')
        self.coinSpin = 0
        self.rect = self.coinsFadeAway[0].get_rect().move(x, y)

    def draw(self, window):
        if not self.coinTouched:
            window.blit(self.coins, (self.x, self.y))
            if self.coinSpin < 11:
                window.blit(self.coinsFadeAway[self.coinSpin], (self.x, self.y))
                self.coinSpin += 1
            elif self.coinSpin > 11:
                self.coinTouched = False

    def hit(self):
        self.coinTouched = True
```

can anyone help me in figuring out how should I delete that coin sprite completely from the screen or a way around so that the coins disappear but score won't get increased when I stay at the coins position

Comment: it's not working = I ain't adding sprites in a group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the collision only if the "Coin" was not hit yet:

```py
def coinsHit_or_not(self, hero, thecoin):

    if not thecoin.coinTouched:
        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(hero, thecoin)
        if hit:
            thecoin.hit()
            self.score += 2
```

Or add a method to the class `Coins` which does collision test:

```py
class Coins(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def collide(self, hero)
        if self.coinTouched:
            return False
        self.coinTouched = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(hero, self)
        return self.coinTouched
```

```py
def coinsHit_or_not(self, hero, thecoin):
    if thecoin.collide(hero)
        self.score += 2
```